# How do I distinguish ADO Database Errors in VB6

Tags: vb6, ado

I'm using ADO to read and write a database from a VB6 application. Naturally, the database access may return errors. I am currently displaying an error message by a method borrowed from here http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/13483 but I would like, in my code, to act differently according to whether the error is an index constraint violation, a column constraint violation, trigger forced an error and so forth.

Would I be right in looking in the .Number part of the first error in the collection? Or the last?

And does anyone know where I might find a list of the error numbers used here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More careful study of the data structure returned reveals it has a member .SQLState, which contains what I am looking for. Apologies to Dan and systempuntoout for not noticing this before.

Answer (score 2):

[ErrorValueEnum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677004%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) specifies the type of ADO run-time error with a list of ADO error codes.

Comment: Thank you, systempuntoout. That is the type of list I am looking for, but I really need one with the what one might call "logical" database errors, rather than those more "mechanical" ones.

Answer (score 1):

No, Err.Number will only contain the error from the ADO standpoint. Database internal errors are database specific. For example, in Oracle nearly all errors that you'd care about match the pattern `ORA-(\d{5})`  and you could pull that value from Err.Description to find out the exact error code.